# Turn on Airplane mode using AccessibilityService Class in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to turn on or off airplane mode using `AccessibilityService`.

Any idea how we can do it?

Comment: How do you want to use Accessibility Service? Basically you can do it with dependency service but if you want more specific way, you need to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't change it from app that target bigger than Android 4.2. But you can open the settings page instead if you want:

```
     if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr1)
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent intentAirplaneMode = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionAirplaneModeSettings);
                    intentAirplaneMode.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    Context.StartActivity(intentAirplaneMode);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.Error("exception", e + "");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");
                intent1.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask); 
                Context.StartActivity(intent1);
            }
   }
```

And AccessibilityService can used with dependency service.

Answer (score 1):

Kamal you’re not going to be able to do it.

It doesn’t seem like you’re doing iOS, but iOS has a lot of limitations due to privacy and security purposes that won’t allow you to do this. You can see more details here stackoverflow.com/q/20469425/11104068

Also android blocked being able to do this from Android 4.2 onwards. Only system apps can make changes to Airplane mode, as you can see here stackoverflow.com/a/5533943/11104068
Since it doesn’t seem you’re creating a system app that gets installed with the operating system, and not through the Play Store, you won’t be able to get permissions. It will give you an error /exception even if you implement everything